# Unable to install packages from local repo - RHEL 7.3

Tags: rhel, yum

I have a box which is cut off from the internet. I need to install RHEL 7.3 with a local repo on this machine. RHEL was installed successfully and a local repo was successfully created as well using an ISO image placed on the server. I followed the steps on the following link.

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-setup-yum-repository-using-locally-mounted-dvd/

However, after setting up the repo, I am unable to install any packages, it successfully finds the packages on the installed media but is unable to install them and gives the following error.

> Install  1 Package (+26 Dependent packages)
>
> Total download size: 11 M
>
> Installed size: 36 M
>
> Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
>
> Downloading packages:
>
> Error downloading packages:
>
> perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

TLDR : Unable to install packages using YUM after setting it up successfully.

Comment: Run "yum repoinfo all" and check the info relevant to the particular repository in question.

Comment: Here is the information, as you can see it is already enabled. @RamanSailopal

https://imgur.com/a/2L0CG

Comment: There is a field called:

Repo-expire and its in the past. What does this indicate? Is this the time after which yum will not install from this repo?

Comment: Looks like dependent package is not in the repository? What happens when you try and install perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64 on it's own?

Comment: Err - The package that you mentioned is in the Packages folder of the mounted CD. However when I try to install it using the rpm command, I get the error - not a rpm package.                   


root@hxcslc-c01:/mnt/Packages [0] 
# rpm -hiv perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):

Comment: I think that is the reason it is trying for mirrors, any idea how I can resolve it?

".rpm error: perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest): "

Comment: Maybe the rpm files didn’t copy correctly? Are they zero-sized?

Comment: No, the size is alright, although whenever I try to install any package, manually (via rpm) or automatically (via yum) it is unable to do so.

`not an rpm package (or package manifest):` @JeffSchaller

Comment: Seems like something got corrupted along the way. What is them output of `file` on one of those rpms?

Comment: Please post text *as text*, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO mounted was corrupted. Figured it out by checking the cksum.